# Create a config file containing connection information then reference that connection

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet which contains VBA code assigned to a button.

**Here is part of my VBA code:**

```vb
Dim ConnectionStr As String
Dim sql As String

ConnectionStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=ABCDEFG;User ID=xyz;Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=NEW_DB"


With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array("OLEDB;" & ConnectionStr), _
    Destination:=Worksheets("Hidden").Range("$A$2")).QueryTable

       .CommandType = xlCmdSql
       .CommandText = "EXECUTE [dbo].[usp_one]"
       .SavePassword = True
       .SaveData = True
       .AdjustColumnWidth = True
       .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_in_Hidden"
       .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End With
```

I don't want to show the connection string in a VBA macro, because someone may "peep" into it and discover our SQL Server password.

It seems one solution would be to create a config file containing the  connection information and then to reference the config file in the VBA macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway, VBA must finally get the password for the connection. No matter it's in a connection string or a config file.

And the connection is established by Excel via VBA, so the password (or a connection string, a config file, etc.) must be distributed with the excel sheet file.

Therefore, if someone has gotten the excel sheet and can use it normally, I don't think there be an effective way to prevent knowing the connection password.

If you wan't the excel sheet's users to make some changes on the database, you'd better not assign them the corresponding database privilege for the database user that the VBA code uses (if the database system supports user privilege limitation).

Comment: Hi,    Thanks for your reply.       If config files are not the answer to hiding server information from too clever users, are there other alternatives?

Comment: As I have said, I don't think there be an effective way to prevent knowing the connection information. But you could limit the database user's privileges in the database system. By this way, too clever users cannot do unauthorized operations without privileges, though they have gotten the connection information.

Comment: For examples, if the excel sheet only need to access database table A, it's recommended to allow the connection to access only the table, and disallow the connection to access other tables, thus we can protected information in other tables.

Comment: Besides, you also could build your application server, and move the database connection client from the excel sheet to your own server. But that requires a higher level of programming technology and make things complicated.